# how to save Azure Data Factory - Copy Data output to a file in ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Does anyone know if this is possible and if not, is there another option to save the output data?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Copy activity is used to simply copy the data from source to the sink with some basic transformation.
You can use the `Linked Service` and `Dataset` to copy the data to a file in the sink.

To Store the file in Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ADLS), you need to have ADLS account.

Create a ADLS account be following simple steps in this Microsoft tutorial – [Create a storage account to use with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/create-data-lake-storage-account).

Then, go to the `Manage` tab on the left panel in your Azure Data Factory and select `Linked Services`, then click `+ New`.

[image]

Search for `Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2` and select the Azure Data Lake Gen2 connector.

[image]

Configure the **Linked Service** by giving a **Name**, **Subscription** name and **Azure Data lake Storage account** name which you have created by following steps in above shared link.

[image]

Later, to create a Dataset, go to `Author` on left Panel, click on Dataset and New Dataset.

[image]

Again, select the `Azure Data Lake Storage gen2` for dataset and now select dataset format which is the type of file which it will store. Refer below image.

[image]

Give dataset a `Name`, Select the `Linked service` which you have created above and click OK.

[image]

Now, in `Copy activity`, under `Sink` tab, select this dataset under `Sink dataset` option. Give `File extension` and run the pipeline using `Debug` option.

[image]